# Passport.js http-bearer Strategy, get req to pass through to function

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js

I'm using the [HTTP Bearer Strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-bearer/)

Here's my Bearer Strategy Code:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    url = require('url'),
    BearerStrategy = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy,
    config = require('../config'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    users = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function() {
    // Use bearer strategy
    passport.use(new BearerStrategy(
        function(token, done) {

            User.findOne({ token: token }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
                return done(null, user, { scope: 'all' });
            });
        }
    ));
};
```

Instead of handling the route function in my routes file (like in their example) I'm using my user.server.controller.js with an exports function like so:

```
// route
app.route('/auth/bearersignin').post(users.bearerSignin);

// export function in user controller
exports.bearerSignin = function(req, res) {
    console.log('bearerSignin', req.user); // CAN DETECT req.user HERE FINE
    passport.authenticate('bearer', {session:false}, function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside authenticate', req.user); // BUT HERE IT'S SHOWING UP null 
        var response = {
            userObj: req.user,
            redirectUrl: req.session.redirectUrl
        };
        res.json(response);
    })(req, res);
};
```

How do I properly construct my exports.bearerSignin function to handle the req and authenticate with Passport?

BTW, here is the JSON for the user object being passed to the exports function:

```
{
    _id: abc123idnumber,
    photo: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/abc123/IMG_2899-square_normal.jpg',
    provider: 'local',
    username: 'userabc123',
    __v: 0,
    created: Tue Aug 23 2016 00:52:20 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    updated: Fri Aug 26 2016 03:53:17 GMT+0000 (UTC),
    freeEventsCount: 1,
    eventsSubscription: false,
    profiles: [],
    roles: [ 'user' ],
    google: {},
    facebook: {},
    twitter: 
     { profilePhoto: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/idabc123/square_normal.jpg',
         name: 'Joe Smith',
         token: 'tokenabc123',
         username: 'tonejac',
         id: 'abc123' },
    localAccountExists: true,
    firstName: 'joe',
    email: 'user@example.com'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is in the wrong place (it's in `passport.authenticate` instead of the returned middleware).

```
exports.bearerSignin = function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('bearer', {
        session: false
    })(req, res, function() { // this is the function called after auth
        console.log('inside authenticate', req.user);
        var response = {
            userObj: req.user,
            redirectUrl: req.session.redirectUrl
        };
        res.json(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: Ohhh... interesting. I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes. (answered pending)